# Adding additional Script in base MasterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have this base masterpage

```
public class NMasterPage : MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
            using (HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(writer))
            {
                htmlWriter.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Script);
                htmlWriter.AddAttribute("src", "http://kamote.com/x.js");
                htmlWriter.RenderEndTag();

                Page.Header.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
            }
        }
    }
```

and a masterpage that inherits the **NMasterPage**

```
public partial class Site : NMasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

but when i set the master page of my page into the MasterPage that is inheriting the baseMasterPage (NMasterPage), it will not render the element  that i rendered in baseMasterPage. Did i miss something? any help would be appreciated..

TIA

Comment: You're inhereting programatically, but what does your `<%@ Master` directive look like on your .master page?

Comment: <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Project.A.Site" %>

Comment: Okay, so that's the Master directive for your Site.master. What about NMasterPage.master? Please update your question to include the Master directives for each one, and properly label them.